# Android How to design a Button to be partially colored

Tags: android, button

all I would like to do is something like this:

[image]

It should be a default Android button design and I want to change the color, dynamically and programmatically. And I don't want any fade effects as I have with gradients.

Can someone help me with that?

Comment: You can simply use a `LinearLayout` as a button OR you can try creating a `layer-list` drawable for a Button ..

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I asked for but this is my solution:

```
Integer iColor = getColor();

Integer scaleWidth = myButton.getWidth();
Integer scaleHeight = myButton.getHeight();

Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myDrawable);
Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, iColor);

wrappedDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, (int)(wrappedDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth()*0.5), (int)(wrappedDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight()*0.5));
ScaleDrawable sd = new ScaleDrawable(wrappedDrawable, 0, scaleWidth, scaleHeight);

myButton.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, sd.getDrawable(), null);
```